# Error "unexpected token" en función PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo esta función y arroja todo normal, pero dice que hay un error de `unexpecten token` una idea que significa:

```
function modificar($nombre, $apellidos, $dni, $dni2, $par, $sector,$localizar, $idusuario, $conexion){
    $direccion= "UPDATE direccion SET 
                  id_par='$sector',sector='$localizar',
                  localizar='$idusuario'
                 WHERE id=$par";
                 echo $direccion;
    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $direccion);
    $query= "UPDATE accidente SET fecha_acd='$nombre',
             tipo_acd='$apellidos',
              h_acd='$dni',
              hrep_acd='$dni2'
             WHERE id=$idusuario";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    echo $resultado;

    verificar_resultado( $resultado );
    cerrar( $conexion );
}
```

---

Éste es el error

> UPDATE direccion SET id_par='15',
>          sector='dsadasdas',
>          localizar='asdadsdas'      WHERE id=1
>
> **Warning**:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   string given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\datatable\guardar.php**
>   on line **97**
>  
>  **Warning**:  mysqli_query() expects
>   parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\datatable\guardar.php** on line
>   **112**
>  {"respuesta":"ERROR"}
>  **Warning**: 
>   mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\datatable\guardar.php** on line
>   **142**

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `$conexion`? Debería ser una conexión MySQLi, pero parece que es una cadena de texto (al menos ese es el mensaje que recibes)

Comment: si la imprimo la variable conexion dice 1

Comment: ¿Cómo llamas a `modificar`? El mensaje de error no coincide con el valor que se imprime

Comment: no coincide descubri que llamaba a la funcion usando una variable dos veces xd pero aun no eh solucionado

Comment: Edita la pregunta para reflejar el problema adecuadamente y que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` no devuelve un conjunto de resultados en consultas tipo `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, sino que devuelve `TRUE` si la consulta fue exitosa, o `FALSE` si no lo fue. Lo que se suele hacer en esos casos es, mediante el método `affected_rows`, determinar el número de filas que fue actualizado o insertado. Por otra parte, estás ejerciendo una mala práctica al no usar consultas preparadas para actualizar, pues podrías tener una Inyección SQL. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo de UPDATE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uu3z-gdy9) aplicando esos criterios. También, es mejor usar código orientado a objetos.

Comment: Como te han comentado: En algún momento tienes que establecer la conexión así `$conexion=mysqli_connect(...)` el problema es que luego estás modificando esa variable `$conexion` con otra cosa. Esa variable no se debería tocar una vez establecida con mysqli_connect. Verifica tu código.